# XSLT 2.0 Advanced calculation includes Cos() Sin()

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, exslt

As I know there's no out of box XSLT function for advanced calculation, anyone have any idea how I can do math such as Cosine/Sin() within XSLT? The requirement is also very specific which I need the extension to be downloadable(instead of pointing to a url) so that I can download it and reference as source within my XSL script. I am unable to download EXSLT source files to try as it seems like there's an issue with that page. Can you please also provide a simple example of how to reference the source within the script and calculate something simple like:

```
<input>
<num1>1</num1>
<num2>1</num2>
</input>
```

and have the output as:

```
<output>
<cosOfnum1>0.54030230586</cosOfnum1>
<sinOfnum2>0.8414709848</sinOfnum2>
</output>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is tagged both `libxslt` and `xslt 2.0` which makes no sense. If you're using `libxslt`, you already have support for EXSLT `math:sin()` and `math:cos()` functions, without having to download or reference anything. Other processor may support their own extensions. With any processor, you could use the [Taylor power series method](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorSeries.html).

Comment: You need to tell us what XSLT processor you are using, and in what environment.

Comment: Sorry, michael.hor257k, I have removed that tag.

Comment: @MichaelKay , I am actually trying to incorporate it into my java application with javax.xml.transformer, instead of doing the math in java, I wanted to find a way to do it in XSLT.

Comment: @R.C. The javax.xml interfaces (generally known as JAXP) are interfaces supported by several XSLT processors, including Xalan, Saxon, and others. So this doesn't tell us which XSLT processor you are using. But it does tell us that you're in the Java environment, which means there are no technical obstacles to using Saxon, which offers the standard XPath 3.0 math function library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saxon 9 (including HE, tested with 9.6, see also http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.6/functions/math/sin.html saying "From Saxon 9.6, available in all editions.") does have out of the box support for the functions defined in https://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math/, here is an example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="input">
        <output>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="num1">
        <cosOfnum1>
            <xsl:value-of select="math:cos(.)"/>
        </cosOfnum1>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="num2">
        <sinOfnum2>
            <xsl:value-of select="math:sin(.)"/>
        </sinOfnum2>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have also tested that XmlPrime 4 runs the above stylesheet correctly when using the command line option `--xt30` so it also has built-in support for those functions.

Altova XMLSpy 2017 also supports the functions in the namespace `xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"` out of the box but only in `version="3.0"` stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

> As I know there's no out of box XSLT function for advanced
>   calculation, anyone have any idea how I can do math such as
>   `Cosine/Sin()` within XSLT?

**Using the FXSL library**, one can have among other things trigonometric functions, written in pure XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0:

http://fxsl.sourceforge.net/articles/xslCalculator/The%20FXSL%20Calculator.html#The_Trigonometric_Functions

**The Math modules of FXSL implement**:

1. The wellknown trigonometric functions: `sin()`, `cos()`, `tan()`, `cot()`, `sec()`, `csc()`
2. Hyperbolic trigonometric functions: `hsin()`, `hcos()`, `htan()`, `hcot()`, `hsec()`, `hcsc()`
3. Exponential and logarithmic functions: `exp()`, `ln()`, `log10()`, `log2()`, `log()`, `pow()`, `sqrt()`
4. Solving equations of one real variable: *the Newton - Raphson's* method and the *Binary Search* method.
5. Inverse functions: `arcsin()`, `arccos()`, `arctan()`, `arccot()`, `arcsec()`, `arccsc()`, `archsin()`, `archcos()`, `archtan()`, `archcot()`, `archsec()`, `archcsc()`,